# Jquery tmpl using join approach for speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I have seen a mention of using JQuery tmpl in a faster way to create a string instead of DOM elements: http://riley.dutton.us/2010/10/12/jquery-templates-vs-jqote-2-a-followup.html

I just can't seem to get it working though.  I am using JQuery 1.6.4 and the latest tmpl files from GitHub.  My code is below - can anyone point out the obvious mistake?  Many thanks.

JsonData is a response from a web service and is correctly formed JSON - I can bind it using the well publicised approad to tmpl and also using JQote2.

jQueryTemplate looks something like:

```
<script id="jQueryTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li><span>${Name}</span><span>${ProductName}</span></li>
</script>
```

My JS to call the template:

```
var myTemplate = $('#jQueryTemplate').template();
var html = myTemplate($, { data: JsonData }).join('');
$("#container").html(html);
```

I seem to get undefined as the result of $('#jQueryTemplate').template(); and this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 
<li><span>${Name}</span><span>${ProductName}</span></li> 
has no method 'join'
```

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging I eventually found an example of this approach explained by Boris Moore.  Thanks Boris for your great work.
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/issues/50

I created a jsperf to compare the two approaches - it is my first jsperf so hopefully it is set up correctly to get meaningful results.  It shows a massive difference. I guess it depends on usage but mine is pretty basic markup generation so the string output combined with .html() will do the trick.
http://jsperf.com/jquery-tmpl-as-string

Hope this helps if you find yourself needing to improve tmpl performance and don't have the opportunity to switch to another templating engine.

Answer (score 2):

define your template like this;

```
$.template( "jQueryTemplate", "<li><span>${Name}</span><span>${ProductName}</span></li>" );
```

render your template like this;

```
$.tmpl( "jQueryTemplate", JsonData ).appendTo( "#container" );
```

or

define your template like this;

```
<script id="jQueryTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li><span>${Name}</span><span>${ProductName}</span></li>
</script>
```

render your template like this;

```
$( "#jQueryTemplate" ).tmpl(JsonData).appendTo("#container" );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I think the approach you mention is the normal, well publicised usage of JQuery tmpl but according to benchmarks and the article I linked to in my post it is over 6 times slower than the approach I was trying to get working.

This was the code I was trying to replicate and failing to do so (taken from para 3 of the article):
template_object($, payload).join("");